# Are prediction results of linear regression inaccurate if data is not IID?

Tags: regression, maximum-likelihood

As I understand minimizing the sum-of-squares error function is equivalent to maximizing the likelihood function and in fact the sum-of-squares error function stems directly from the derivation of maximizing the likelihood. The likelihood function is dependent on the fact that the data is IID. Hence, what would happen if the data were not IID? Would the sum-of-square errors no longer be the maximum likelihood solution and therefore not the best solution anymore? Would this make predictions less accurate? I would assume we would still find the best line fitting the data, but that the generalization error of the model would be large if we tested it on an IID test set. Is this true?

Comment: There are other assumptions to get SSE minimization to coincide with maximum likelihood, chiefly *normal* errors.

Comment: This is unclear. First, how can regression be based on IID data. That is not necessarily an assumption. Second, likelihood functioncs can be constructed without need of IID ...